# eliminate null values with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose we have a table (or a query result) as following:

```
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| station_nr | station_name | mode_1 | mode_2 | mode_3 | mode_4 |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 22         | MTO22        | Large  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 22         | MTO22        | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | XLARGE |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 22         | MTO22        | NULL   | Medium | Null   | Null   |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

we need group by station_nr and _name into and eliminate null values, the desired result is like:

```
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| station_nr | station_name | mode_1 | mode_2 | mode_3 | mode_4 |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 22         | MTO22        | Large  | Medium | NULL   | XLARGE |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Your problem is probably with the underlying query.  You should actually fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MAX()`:

```
SELECT 
    station_mr, 
    station_name, 
    MAX(mode_1) mode_1, 
    MAX(mode_2) mode_2, 
    MAX(mode_3) mode_3,
    MAX(mode_4) mode_4
FROM mytable
GROUP BY station_mr, station_name
```

`MAX()` ignores `NULL` values. This would also work with `MIN()`.

Beware, however, that if one of your column has two non-null values for a given station, only one of them will show up (the greatest, alphabetically).

Comment: yes, each column contains only non-null value and the rest are all null. @GMB